# How to add items into a dictionary from a txt file

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a txt file (that I can't modify) with several thousands of movies in it and I'm supposed to pick out the actors, place and year specifically. I managed to turn it into data like so:

```
f = open("/content/drive/My Drive/netflix.txt", "r")
data = [i.strip('\n').split('\t') for i in open("/content/drive/My Drive/netflix.txt")]
print(data)
```

where it displays it as ['title', 'director', 'cast', 'country', 'release_year'] but I need it to ignore the first two entirely and check how many times each actor in the cast has been mentioned in the file between two years that it gets through inputs.

I can't figure out how I'm supposed to sort it according to the year and country, then count the times a name is mentioned. I'd appreciate some help.

I've only managed to write the part that takes the inputs of two years and the country and checks their validity.

Comment: You are opening the file twice. `f` is already a handle to the file, so use it instead of opening the file again in your list comprehension. Then in your question you mention that you wrote the part that takes the inputs of two years and the country, but you haven't posted any code that does this.

Comment: could you copy/paste a texte file sample to deal with ?

Comment: It looks like your file could be a TSV file, can you please provide a sample of the first few lines?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your txt file is something like this:

```
title   director        cast    country release_year
a       b       c       d       e
a1      b1      c1      d1      e1
a2      b2      c2      d2      e2
```

where the separator is a `\t`, this code should work:

```py
data = {}

with open("./file.txt", "r+") as file:
    # read all lines
    lines = file.readlines()
    # slicing needed to remove legend
    for line in lines[1:]:
        tokens = line.strip().split("\t")
        title = tokens[0]
        actors = tokens[2]
        place = tokens[3]
        year = tokens[4]

        data[title] = {}
        data[title]["actors"] = actors
        data[title]["place"] = place
        data[title]["year"] = year

import json
print(json.dumps(data, indent=3))
```

Output of the script:

```
{
   "a": {
      "actors": "c",
      "place": "d",
      "year": "e"
   },
   "a1": {
      "actors": "c1",
      "place": "d1",
      "year": "e1"
   },
   "a2": {
      "actors": "c2",
      "place": "d2",
      "year": "e2"
   }
}
```

If this is not what you were looking for, please add some detail about the first lines of the txt file.